# The proper test statistic for variables which are functions of multinomials

Tags: statistical-significance, multinomial-distribution

This may be very basic but I'm drawing a blank and google isn't helping ... In an A/B setting I'm comparing two random variables $X_a$ and $X_b$.
$$
X_a = \frac{\sum X_{ai} * C_i}{\sum X_{ai}}
$$
and
$$
X_b = \frac{\sum X_{bi} * C_i}{\sum X_{bi}}
$$
where $i \in \{0, ..., N\}$ and $C_i$ are constant coefficients. $N \approx 10$.

Expressing as $x_{ai} = \frac{X_{ai}}{\sum X_{ai}}$ and $x_{bi} = \frac{X_{bi}}{\sum X_{ai}}$ what I'm really after is a test for significance of

$$
X_a - X_b = \sum{(x_{ai} - x_{bi}) * C_i}
$$

But this is a function of multinomials $x_{ai}$ and $y_{ai}$. How do I go about constructing such test?

Comment: One important prequel to constructing such a test is to state your assumptions about the distributions of the $X_{ai}.$  What are those variables, what do they represent, and what might their distributions be?

Comment: Thank you, @whuber, my omission. Xs are counts. A concrete example might be a store that has 10 products. I have two groups of customers with 100 people in each. Each person has to buy one item. A and B are different arrangements of products in the store. In the end I'd like to not only reason about differences in distributions over products but also whether I significantly improved the overall revenue.